# Displaying id of current slide using jQuery & anything slider

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I'm trying to have the id of the current slide written in another div as the slide changes. This might give you an idea of what I am trying to acheive:

```
$(function(){
 $('#slider').anythingSlider({
    onSlideInit: function(e,slider){
        var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#slide-change').html(currentID);
    }
 });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
            <div id="slider-wrapper">
                <div id="slider">
                    <div id="1"><img src="images/slider/slide1.jpg" /></div>
                    <div id="2"><img src="images/slider/slide2.jpg" /></div>
                    <div id="3"><img src="images/slider/slide3.jpg" /></div>
                    <div id="4"><img src="images/slider/slide4.jpg" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It is sort of working - when the slide changes, it is displaying the word 'slider' though. This is probably a very basic question, apologies, but how do I get it to display the id of the current slide, as opposed to the container? I'm sure it's just a case of using the correct selector, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You might want to use `onSlideComplete` which excepts just `slider` instead and see what's available to you in the `slider` object. If there's a slide index you could use that to select the current div, otherwise you might have to track it yourself.

Comment: I apologise, I'm fairly new to jQuery, you might have to spell it out for me a bit. How would I access the attributes of the slider object? Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the slider appends a class of `activePage` to the active slider. Using that you can access the current slide.

**Edit:** Per Mottie's comment.

```
var holder = $('#slide-change'); //'cache' the object
var mySlider = $('#slider').anythingSlider({
    onSlideComplete: function(slider){
        console.log(slider); //here you can investigate the slider object in your browser's console
        holder.html(slider.$currentPage.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Try using `slider.$currentPage` inside of the `onSlideComplete` callback instead - [ref](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Callbacks-and-Events#wiki-arguments)

Comment: @Mottie Awesome, didn't see that.